# Multi-threaded evaluations over a Channel in julia

Tags: multithreading, julia, channel

I woud like to simultaneously use a `Channel` to produce values at which a function must be evaluated, and parallelise the evaluation of this function using `Threads.@threads`.
In the absence of any multi-threading, my MWE is:

```
#####
# Produces input values
function producer(c::Channel)
    nb_inputs = rand(1:10)
    for n=1:nb_inputs
        println("Generating | ",n)
        put!(c,n)
    end
end
#####
# Expensive function
function f(n::Int64)
    println("Running | ",n)
    sleep(2.0)
end
#####
# Evaluates the function over all the input values
function test()
    for n in Channel(producer)
        f(n)
    end
end
#####
test()
```

Here, `producer(c)` returns input values; `f(n)` is an expensive function (whose evaluations are all independent from one another); and `test()` evaluates the function over all the input values returned by the producer.
Now, I would like to run the `for` loop in `test()` in parallel over multiple threads.
Naively, I tried

```
Threads.@threads for n in Channel(producer)
```

Yet, this fails because the number of elements of the `Channel` is initially unknown.
How could I circumvent this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Iterating over a `Channel` is thread safe: you can just use an outer `@threads` loop.

```
using Base.Threads

## ------------------------------------------------------------
# Produces input values
function producer(c::Channel)
    nb_inputs = rand(1:10)
    for n=1:nb_inputs
        println("Generating | ", n, " at: ", threadid())
        put!(c,n)
    end
end

## ------------------------------------------------------------
# Expensive function
function f(n::Int64)
    println("Running | ", n, " at: ", threadid())
    sleep(2.0)
end

## ------------------------------------------------------------
# Evaluates the function over all the input values
function test()
    Ch = Channel(producer)
    @threads for _ in 1:nthreads()
        for n in Ch
            f(n)
        end
    end
end

## ------------------------------------------------------------
test()

## ------------------------------------------------------------
# Or in julia > v1.6
function test()
    Ch = Channel(producer)
    Threads.foreach(Ch) do n
        f(n)
    end
end

## ------------------------------------------------------------
test()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, from your MWE, that you do not know how many times you will call producer() until runtime?  If so, you can index your loops on that value at runtime:

```
const nputs = [Threads.nthreads()]  # or whatever you need it to be > 0

# Produces input values
function producer(c::Channel)
    for n in 1:4
        println("Generating | ", n)
        put!(c,n)
    end
end
#####
# Expensive function
function f(n::Int64)
    println("Running | ", n)
    sleep(2.0)
end
#####
# Evaluates the function over all the input values
function test()
    @Threads.threads for n in 1:first(nputs)
        Channel(producer, first(nputs) * 4)
        f(n)
    end
end

#####
test()
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not know a priori the number of elements that will be created by the producer. I have updated my MWE to account for this constraint.  Having a glance of some upcoming features for [Julia v1.6](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/master/base/threads_overloads.jl), I figured that my solution might be in this patch of code?